# how to troubleshoot orleans when deployed to azure

Tags: azure, orleans

i am running the Azure Web Sample for orleans.  it runs just fine on local dev server.  However, when i deploy to Azure i can't get a response back from the silo.

The deployment is successful.  The web role starts up but when i click on 'ask orleans for details', i get the 'talking to orleans...' but that disapears after about 30 seconds.  i'm left with the taunting 'hoping i will get a response...' message.

no configuration at all.  i took the sample project and the steps from the online tutorial.  published as they instructed and then nothing.

From debugging the web role, it looks like AzureClient it getting some unknown error:

> Error: 0 : Client.Initialize failed with exc -- One or more errors
> occurred.. Will try again
>
> Information: 0 : Pausing 00:00:05 awaiting silo and gateways
> registration for Deployment=70c88c32f1114e168826d757f982a210

I notice that the web role and worker role are sitting on different subnets.  Going to dig into whether there are firewalls preventing communication between the servers.

Any suggestions on what could be broken?  or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: It would probably help to edit your question, to show how you configured orleans in the role. Otherwise this sounds pretty vague.

Comment: The Silo and Client should be in the same deployment. Is this the case?

Comment: yes, they are in the same deployment.  i ended up creating a VNET and assigning it to the silo and client.  that seemed to do the trick.  my belief is that the webrole and workerrole were on separate subnets and couldn't communicate with each other.  The added bonus is that i can use a web app to talk with the silo.